# Lost space on MacBook Air 2020

Tags: macbook-pro

I have lost some space on my MacBook Air 2020 (512 GB SSD)

I ran Boot Camp Assistant and installed Windows some time ago. I only had 110 GB or so for Windows which was not enough. I got curious and boot my MacBook in macOS for the first time in months and ran the Disk Utility to reveal there were 2 BOOTCAMP partitions. One was 110 GB or so with another being around 220 GB. It seems as though I created two BOOTCAMP partitions. I have tried to no avail to reclaim the space. Don't ask me what I did but I ran some commands and managed to delete the second BOOTCAMP partition but cannot reclaim the space.

What I am after is to have the maximum amount of space for my Windows partition and remove any unnecessary partitions I have created, hopefully without having to reinstall Windows. I don't know why I have 5 volume counts and "4 child mounts". I am very uneducated in this area.

I honestly have no clue about Apple and Mac so please go easy on me.

I have included a screenshot of my `diskutil list` from the Terminal command.

Please advise if anything further is required to assist.

[image: Screenshot of Terminal window showing the output of the 'diskutil list' command]

Comment: Kurt Lewis, Welcome to Ask Different. Please do not upload images of _command output_ from **Terminal** as an image. Just copy and paste it from **Terminal** as text.  Then use _code formatting_ around it by selecting the text and press the `{ }` . button in the edit window. Thanks.

Comment: I thinks the best way is suppress all Windows spaces, add all disk space to Mac os x (without lost data), then re-create windows space with BootCamp. I can give you terminal commands to do this if you want.

Comment: Hi Jean. Thanks for your comment. That would be great. Just to confirm, will this delete my windows partition and require re-installing windows? Thanks